# standards of using and naming of pointer to function as delegates in C++

Tags: c++, delegates, standards, function-pointers

There are certain questions in my mind:

1. What is the standard for naming pointer to functions as delegates?
2. What is the best way to define signature of functions in this matter?
3. What are the techniques of maintaining safety and stability of code
       when using this pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no **standard** for such naming, only conventions that vary from project to project (or company to company). Common rules include avoiding leading underscores in such names (reserved for the standard library)
2. There is no best way to "define a signature", it's the same as for any other functions: choose explicit and clear names for both the method name and its arguments.
3. The best advise is to **avoid explicit pointers to functions**, and prefer using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) , a powerful polymorphic function wrapper.